# Kafka Java Consumer SDK long pull without using while

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I try to use Kafka Java SDK to implement a consumer however most consumer examples I saw are using `while(true)` loop and inside the loop call `consume` method to get a message.

```
while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords =
                    consumer.poll(1000);
            if (consumerRecords.count()==0) {
                noRecordsCount++;
                if (noRecordsCount > giveUp) break;
                else continue;
            }
            consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
                System.out.printf("Consumer Record:(%d, %s, %d, %d)\n",
                        record.key(), record.value(),
                        record.partition(), record.offset());
            });
            consumer.commitAsync();
        }
```

I am wondering are there any elegant way to handle this without using `while` loop which is similar to RabbitMQ implementation following:

```
Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
      @Override
      public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
          throws IOException {
        String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
      }
    };
    channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
```

Comment: you can try using `Spring-kafka` library so you can just add `@kafkaListener` annotation on top of any method, you don't need it to loop

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Spring-kafka` which has `@KafkaListener` annotation and makes the method to listen topic, for more info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka)

Because in apache-kafka there is no elegant way to make method as a listener to topic, since consumer need to poll records for certain intervals, needed that code in loop

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topicName", group = "foo")
public void listen(String message) {
System.out.println("Received Messasge in group foo: " + message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Poll Loop is the only way to consume the messages in Kafka. The elegant code to handle the message should be within the loop.

Comment: There are libraries available that provide higher-level abstractions (such as Spring-kafka, or any of the streaming frameworks), so that you don't have to see the poll-loop yourself, though.

Comment: True, the question didn't ask for external libraries but for java implementation. So kept my answer to that.